# Override CreateMap - Automapper

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I have the follow map. All decimal type number has be a 2 decimal places.

```
CreateMap<decimal, decimal>().ConvertUsing(x => decimal.Round(x, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```

But sometimes, i need more decimals places, for example

```
CreateMap<T, R>.ForMember(x => x.Total, x => x.MapFrom(x => decimal.Round(x.Items.Sum(x => x.Price * x.Quantity), 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)))
```

Is it possible to override the global CreateMap in certain "CreateMap"? Thx

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Value-transformers.html

Answer (score 0):

One option is that when you call the mapper.Map, you can provide options that override the current map profile using the inline mapping like so.

```
_mapper.Map(T, R, opt => opt.ConfigureMap().ForMember(x => x.Total, x => x.MapFrom(x => decimal.Round(x.Items.Sum(x => x.Price * x.Quantity), 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)));
```